# Как убрать ошибку "Array to string conversion" в собственном виджете Yii2 Advanced?

Tags: php, yii2

Здравствуйте!

Создаю свой вывод виджет для вывода мета-тэгов на `views`. Но при `return` результата получаю ошибку:

> Array to string conversion

Насколько я понимаю, Yii2 принимает для `return` только строку, а не массив, да? Если да - как это можно обойти? Либо придётся делать костыль с implode/explode?

Код виджета:

```
<?php

namespace app\components;


use yii\base\Widget;
use common\models\MetaTag;

class MetaTags extends Widget
{
    public $page;

    public function init()
    {
        parent::init();

    }

    public function run()
    {
        return MetaTag::find()->where(['page' => $this->page])->asArray()->one();
    }
}
```

Пытаюсь вывести результат обычным var_dump:

```
<?
    var_dump(MetaTags::widget(['page' => 'reviews']));
?>
```

Comment: Можете сделать renderPartial и создать partial view. Это способ наиболее правильный и удобный.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В виджете можно через `return` вернуть строку и, также, просто через `echo`, `print` выводят. Особо не парит. Почему не массив - хз. Дело, должно быть, не в `var_dump`, а в `yii\base\widget`. Виджет, скорее всего, сам уже выводит через `echo` результат от `run`.

Вот примерчики для способов вывода

**Для одного значения**

```
<?php

namespace app\components;


use yii\base\Widget;
use common\models\MetaTag;

class MetaTags extends Widget
{
    public $page;

    public function init()
    {
        parent::init();

    }

    public function run()
    {
        return MetaTag::find()->where(['page' => $this->page])->scalar();
    }
}
```

---

**Для нескольких строк**

```
<?php

namespace app\components;


use yii\base\Widget;
use common\models\MetaTag;

class MetaTags extends Widget
{
    public $page;

    public function init()
    {
        parent::init();

    }

    public function run()
    {
        foreach(MetaTag::find()->where(['page' => $this->page])->column() as $tag) {
            echo $tag;
        }
    }
}
```

---

**Для нескольких моделей**

Забыл напрочь, как там мета теги пишутся. Немного псевдомета-теги.
А может, вообще, хелпер/хелперы `yii\helpers\Html` для меты есть.

```
<?php

namespace app\components;


use yii\base\Widget;
use yii\helpers\Html;
use common\models\MetaTag;

class MetaTags extends Widget
{
    public $page;

    public function init()
    {
        parent::init();

    }

    public function run()
    {
        foreach(MetaTag::find()->where(['page' => $this->page])->all() as $tag) {
            if ($tag->type == 'description') {
                echo Html::beginTag('meta', ['type' => $tag->type, 'description' => $tag->value]);
            } elseif ($tag->type == 'keywords') {
                echo Html::beginTag('meta', ['type' => $tag->type, 'keywords' => $tag->value]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: В принципе, я тоже так подумал. Сразу в HTML там всё обработал и вернул строку с ним. 

Также ещё как вариант можно в JSON декодить/энкодить, но это тоже костыль, но уже не такой плохой, как  с implode/explode.